# Tensorflow not detecting GPU in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, gpu, conda

I was having some trouble getting tensorflow with GPU support to work in jupyternotebook. Here is my setup so far.

1. Create a new conda environment
2. `conda install -c conda-forge jupyter`
3. Follow the setup on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux
4. Install the `nvidia-pyindex` package
5. Install the `nvidia-tensorrt` package

However, it appears that tensorflow is only detecting my GPU in the conda env terminal, but not in my jupyternotebook.

Comment: Are you sure that the notebook is running the same kernel - i.e. your conda env? You can try `!which python` in a jupyter cell to get some idea if its the same.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth `!which python` appears to be returning a python variable inside of my env, however what I am more concerned about is that `!echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty inside of my notebook